# Geometric construction of catenary

Tags: geometry

Can anyone explain the steps of the Leibniz geometric construction for the catenary curve?

Leibniz does a complete job, I'm sure, but I still cannot follow with certainty:

[image]
It is difficult to follow the progression of steps with only the one geometric figure. It would be awesome to see all the individual steps from blank page to completed diagram for the varying parameters such as (length of chain and width to develop depth, length of chain and depth to develop width, and width and depth to calculate length) .

Thanks,

Rick Rempe